# Having trouble configuring Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel with intellij and whenever I run my project this is what it looks like in the web browser

[image]

I'm not sure if I set up Laravel correctly on intellij. I set it up for XAMPP because I thought that was the problem however my pages are still looking like the image above.

Comment: what is your file extension for this particular view?

Comment: Are you just opening the file by double-clicking on it? Does the URL show `http://` or does it say `file:///`? (It should say http)

Comment: I open the file using the browser icons that appear on the corner. It runs through http://localhost:63342/ and then the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

probably it's not laravel problem. Maybe is better to setup local server in right way. You can try:
`php artisan serve`
under laravel root dir and then open in http://localhost:8000  in browser

Answer (score 0):

Those icons are trying to use php built in server and may not be configured to match your laravel project. I get the same thing as you with localhost:63342 when clicking web browser preview icons in my Symfony project. I just configured phpStorm preview icons to load based on my web server root.

When using laravel, trying to load your blade views directly will most likely run into issues. Your request is not being mapped to a route/controller for it to be properly handled. For my symfony project and after configuring phpStorm, i get sent to app.dev/app/Resources/views/test.php, which is not a valid route (proves point of previous sentence). You will most likely get the same issue in your laravel project.

You can configure your phpStorm preview icons to load to your localhost:8000 / app.dev or whatever you may have set your app host to.
Follow the below phpStorm articles if you want to mess with this some more.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/working-with-web-servers-copying-files.html
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/creating-a-local-server-configuration.html